# Simplifying an ArcTan expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

The expression $\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{L^2 \sin ^2(\theta )}}{\sqrt{L^2 \cos ^2(\theta )}}\right)$ can be simplified to $\theta$.

After some attempts I got the following to do the job.

```
ArcTan[Sqrt[L^2 Cos[θ]^2], Sqrt[L^2 Sin[θ]^2]] // 
PowerExpand // TrigToExp // Simplify // PowerExpand
```

It appears rather clunky to me. Is there a better way to simplify this expression.

Comment: Please see http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1044/1356 for formatting questions with greek letters easily.

Comment: Öskå, thanks for pointing that out. I had wondered how that was done.

Comment: I don't think mathematically it is true that the argument of `ArcTan` can be simplified to theta...what if theta=3Pi/4?

Comment: @Leo Fang, doesn't $n/n$ simplify to 1, even though it would be problematic if $n=0$. (Although I fail to see any thing problematic with the ArcTan expression when $\theta =\frac{3 \pi }{4}$).

Comment: @SubaThomas, in this case when θ=3π/4, `Sqrt[L^2 Sin[θ]^2]/Sqrt[L^2 Cos[θ]^2]` gives 1, and `ArcTan[1]=π/4` which is NOT 3π/4 as you expected. Signs of `Sin` and `Cos` do matter.

Comment: To be more precise, note that the range of arctan is [-π/2, π/2]

Comment: @Leo Fang, thanks for clarifying your point. I would like for it to simplify as $\tan ^{-1}(\tan (\theta ))$   and then as $\theta$.

Comment: @Leo Fang, I think you are missing the point. I have already got the expression to simplify to $\theta$. I was looking for a cleaner way.

Comment: @SubaThomas, if you're so sure that θ>0, try `Simplify[
 ArcTan[Sqrt[L^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2], Sqrt[L^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2]], 
 Assumptions -> {Pi/2 > \[Theta] > 0, L > 0}]`. I just wanted to warn you that there is a potential risk to treat arctan(tan(θ))= θ...

Comment: @SubaThomas, I think I am not missing the point. The point you had such a clunky expression is that you missed the fact sin(θ) may give a minus sign, and that's why you had to use `PowerExpand` to simplify it (`PowerExpand` assumes everything is real and positive, so the problem here is avoided). For a cleaner way see my comment above using `Assumptions `.

Comment: @ Leo Fang, thanks for you suggestion, but it quite is not going to solve my problem. I was experimenting with modeling a simple pendulum in cartesian coordinates ($x=L \sin (\theta )$) and then converting it to polar coordinates ($\theta$). I cannot assume that $\theta$ will not be negative.

Answer (score 6):

the most you can generally simplify is:

```
Simplify[ArcTan[ Sqrt[ L^2 Sin[t]^2]/Sqrt[ L^2 Cos[t]^2]], 
    Assumptions -> {L > 0, Element[t, Reals]}]

(* ArcTan[Sqrt[1/Cot[t]^2]] *)
```

your original statement is true only on 0-Pi/2

```
Simplify[ArcTan[ Sqrt[ L^2 Sin[t]^2]/Sqrt[ L^2 Cos[t]^2]], 
   Assumptions -> {L > 0, 0 < t < Pi/2}]
```

(* t *)

now a fair question, why doesnt Simplyfy return `-t` here.. ?

```
 Simplify[ArcTan[ Sqrt[ L^2 Sin[t]^2]/Sqrt[ L^2 Cos[t]^2]], 
    Assumptions -> {L > 0, -Pi/2 < t < 0}]
```

or better we'd like to see Abs[t] for `-Pi/2 < t < Pi/2`

Comment: Yeah this is a interesting question...In fact `Simplify[Sqrt[ L^2 Sin[t]^2]/Sqrt[ L^2 Cos[t]^2], 
    Assumptions -> {L > 0, -Pi/2 < t < 0}]` is not really simplified either, so the question is irrelevant of `ArcTan`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. My eventual solution was to reformulate the expression as $\sin ^{-1}(\sin (\theta ))$ and use PowerExpand.